# What's the meaning of strict version in haskell?

Tags: lazy-evaluation, haskell, strictness

Follow <Real World Haskell> , it is said  `foldl'` are strict version of `foldl`.

But it's hard for me to understand , what does `strict` mean??

```
foldl f z0 xs0 = lgo z0 xs0
         where
            lgo z []     =  z
            lgo z (x:xs) = lgo (f z x) xs


foldl' f z0 xs0 = lgo z0 xs0
    where lgo z []     = z
          lgo z (x:xs) = let z' = f z x in z' `seq` lgo z' xs
```

Comment: Compare the source code for the two versions of foldl, and you might be enlightened.

Comment: @augustss maybe, can you answer this?

Comment: As you can see, foldl' computes the first argument to lgo before the call, whereas foldl will (in general) pass a thunk that will get evaluated when needed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Haskell - strict vs non-strict with foldl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13533586/haskell-strict-vs-non-strict-with-foldl)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

foldl and (the strict) foldl' are close to semantically equivalent.  The difference is in performance, especially when you are transversing a large list.  The laziness has an overhead of building a thunk and foldl' is the more efficient way to arrive at that result because it doesn't build a huge thunk.

There is a really good article explaining this in detail on [Haskell Wiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl%27)

Strict functions works like functions in C or other languages in that their arguments are generally eagerly evaluated.

Answer (score 13):

It is not widely known, but `foldl'` is actually non-strict in its accumulator argument! Recall the type:

```
foldl' :: (a -> b -> a) -> a -> [b] -> a
```

Its strictness in argument 2 depends on the strictness of the function given for argument 1, as you see if you pass `const`:

```
Prelude Data.List> foldl' (const (+1)) undefined [1]
2
Prelude Data.List> foldl' (const (+1)) undefined [1..4]
5
```

You would have thought, naively, that "foldl' is strict" means "strict in the accumulator argument". The above contradicts that.

However, it is even more insidious, as the strictness is only on the result of the function application in the cons case of the loop. So you still get bottoms if you enter the base case, but not the inductive case:

```
Prelude Data.List> foldl' (const (+1)) undefined []
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
```

So the strictness [in argument 2](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/Data-List.html#foldl%27) *also* depends on the *value* of argument 3!

This is how I'd write it: "fully" strict in its 2nd argument.

```
foldl' f z0 xs0 = go z0 xs0
  where
    go !z []     = z
    go !z (x:xs) = go (f z x) xs
```

Which is truly strict in its second argument, as you can see :

```
Prelude Data.List.Stream> foldl' (\a b -> 1) undefined [undefined]
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
```

Compared with the Haskell2010 version:

```
Prelude Data.List.Stream> Data.List.foldl' (\a b -> 1 ) undefined [undefined]
1
```

This actuall has a practical impact -- the current definition will not unbox its accumulator argument consistently.

Historical note: this was discovered when we were specifying the list library's strictness semantics for the stream fusion paper in 2007, and the approach to specifying strictness is given in Duncan Coutt's [PhD thesis](http://community.haskell.org/~duncan/thesis.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

A strict function is a function whose arguments are evaluated before the body is.

Comment: No, it's not a function whose arguments are evaluated before the call.  A strict function is, informally, a function which evaluates its arguments.

Comment: Tinctorius, what do you mean?

Comment: Formally, a function is strict in an argument if it returns bottom when that argument is bottom.  This means a function can be strict, in the formal sense, without evaluating the argument.  This might sound like splitting hairs, but it's important when doing strictness analysis.

Comment: @augustss That's not what's meant in this context though, is it? `foldl` evaluates to bottom in the same cases that `foldl'` does - it just does so later, no?

Comment: @sepp2k: No. For example: `foldl (\x y -> y) (error "empty") [1,undefined,2]` is 2, but the same expression with `foldl'` is ⊥.