# Why are even lazy folds so eager?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

This code:

```
import Data.Foldable
import Debug.Trace

factors :: [Bool]
factors = [True, True, False, True, True, True, True, True]

andy :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
andy False _ = False
andy True False = False
andy True True = True

tandy :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool 
tandy a b = let c = a `andy` b in trace (show a ++ " & " ++ show b ++ " = " ++ show c) c

wonder :: Bool
wonder = foldl tandy True factors
```

says this when I evaluate `wonder`:

```
True & True = True  
True & True = True  
True & False = False
False & True = False
False & True = False
False & True = False
False & True = False
False & True = False
```

but I would have preferred it to have stopped sooner. I've tried this with everything imaginable in place of the `foldl` and with `&&` in place of `andy` but it never seems to get the hint.

It seems to me that the line `andy False _ = False` doesn't invite the compiler to evaluate the second parameter. I haven't forced any strictness. What's going on? Even C can do better.

Comment: Have you looked at the implementation of `foldl` to try to understand what is going on? Try the same using `foldr` instead. Any difference?

Comment: foldl, foldl', foldr, foldr', foldMap, foldMap': the traces come out in a different order but never any less of them. foldl is the right choice: not strict and not starting from the right. I think it should terminate soon. I think foldr should also terminate soon.

Comment: I also wrote my own foldl as `foldl_ f z (a:as) = foldl_ f (f z a) as` plus a base case. Same result.

Comment: You might find https://stackoverflow.com/a/13534285/869736 interesting reading.

Comment: Interesting indeed but it doesn't undermine my expectation.

Comment: It seems like an inefficiency in Haskell: it thinks `andy` is strict in the second parameter cos it can't figure out that strictness in one parameter can depend on the value of another. Would it be feasible to fix that?

Comment: The code is only doing exactly what you told it to.  What else could it do?

Comment: I'm not surprised that the tail-recursive implementations run through the full list, but I thought that `myFoldl f s [] = s; myFoldl f s (x:xs) = f x (myFoldl f s xs)` would not do that. It does, however.

Comment: As you expect `andy False x` will not evaluate `x`. It will, though, evaluate its _first_ argument. Since `foldl` produces `andy (andy (andy ...) ...) ...`, and `andy` is strict on the fist argument, this will evaluate more than you want. (`foldl` will also always scan the whole list, but that's to be expected since the outermost `andy` call is `andy something lastElement`)

Comment: Your `myFoldl` is the definition of `foldr`, I think.

Comment: chi: I think `foldl` would produce `andy True (andy b1 (andy b2 ...))` if the list is `[b1, b2]` so strictness in the first argument doesn't force calling a further any after a False. I reckon it thinks `andy` is strict in both arguments. md2perpe's is foldr. Mine is foldl.

Comment: Of course it doesn't think that. The problem is `tandy`, not `andy`.

Comment: @AdrianMay That's essentially a _right_ fold, i.e. `f x1 (f x2 (f x3 z))`. A left fold produces instead `f (f (f z x1) x2) x3`. If you want to exploit the laziness of `andy` you need `f x1 (f x2 (f x3 z))`, so a right fold.

Comment: Carl thinks the traces are causing it? I think not cos I often have trouble with traces not appearing because of laziness.

Comment: Yes, the traces make `tandy` strict in both arguments.

Comment: chi: I wrote `foldl_ f z (a:as) = foldl_ f (f z a) as`. A left fold. No?

Comment: I just changed it to `tandy a b = let c = andy a b in trace (show c) c`. Same number of traces.

Comment: Oh but if I also change to foldr, it terminates when I wish!!!

Comment: But the standard foldl goes all the way to the end of the list

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`tandy` is strict in both parameters, even though `andy` is not. This is because of the tracing. You ask it to show both inputs in the call to `trace`, so it has to evaluate both arguments.

Consider `tandy2':

```
tandy2 :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
tandy2 False _ = trace ("False & anything = False") False
tandy2 True b = trace ("True & " ++ show b ++ " = False") b
```

Instead of blindly evaluating both arguments in its tracing, it is careful to only evaluate the same arguments it would otherwise. This makes it actually reflect the same strictness properties as `andy` has.

Try using `tandy2` with `foldr` and you'll see it stops evaluating as soon as it hits a `False`.

```
$ ghci
GHCi, version 9.2.1: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
ghci> import Debug.Trace
ghci> let tandy2 False _ = trace ("False & anything = False") False ; tandy2 True b = trace ("True & " ++ show b ++ " = False") b
ghci> foldr tandy2 True []
True
ghci> foldr tandy2 True [True]
True & True = False
True
ghci> foldr tandy2 True [True, False]
False & anything = False
True & False = False
False
ghci> foldr tandy2 True [True, False, True]
False & anything = False
True & False = False
False
```

There you go. It never evaluates the `False` branch more than once.

Comment: Note that the behavior may depend on optimization flags.  For me, in GHCi and compiled with `-O0`, the new `tandy2` generates all trace lines.  I need `-O2` to observe it "stopping".

Comment: @K.A.Buhr Cannot repro.  Works exactly as expected in ghci for me.

Comment: If I only trace `a` or `b` and use the predefined `foldl` then the complete list will be traced anyways. But if I trace `a` and use `myFoldl f s [] = s; myFoldl f s (x:xs) = f x (myFoldl f s xs)` then it stops at the first `False`.

Comment: @md2perpe yes, that's a difference between `foldl` and `foldr`. Your `myFoldl` is a strangely-named `foldr`.

Comment: So tracing the value of the second parameter was half of the problem. The other half is foldl vs foldr. I still don't understand why foldl forced it to go all the way.

Comment: @Carl -- it might be dependent on Haskell version.  (I'm using 8.10.7.)  You'll just have to believe me -- I'm staring at the output in GHCi of the OPs original code with `tandy` replaced by your `tandy2`.  In GHCi and compiled with `main = print wonder`, flags `-O0` give eight trace lines; flags `-O2` give only three.

Comment: @AdrianMay It's not exactly tracing the second paramter that was the problem. As you can see, my second equation for `tandy2` traces the second parameter. The problem is tracing a parameter that wouldn't have been evaluated otherwise.

Comment: @K.A.Buhr original code as in using `foldl`?

Comment: Original code as in copying the OPs code block with `foldl`.  I didn't see you had switched to `foldr`.

Comment: @K.A.Buhr Then you're using `foldl` instead of `foldr`.

Comment: So the conclusion seems to be that (1) my tracing was daft, (2) foldr works as expected, (3) foldl only works as expected with optimisations. Is there any reason for it to evaluate the whole thing with optimisations off?

Comment: @AdrianMay I think whether foldl works as expected depends on what you expect. `foldr` works nicely with functions lazy in their first argument; `foldl` works nicely with functions lazy in their second argument. Compare `let tandy3 _ False = trace "a" False; tandy3 b True = trace "b" b in foldl tandy3 True factors`.

Comment: I figured it out. It just wants to know when the list will be empty. It's not really doing the && all the way.